# Permanently add item to combobox

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I have a comboBox which has a few items in it already. 
At Run time, I add an item to it, which gets added successfully.
But when, at the end of the execution, the JFrame is loaded again, the recently added item isn't present.
I used both the methods, using model.addElement() and using additem() and both have the same problem.

Here's the code:

```
 int i = JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE; 
       String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter new item", "Add", i);

       DefaultComboBoxModel model = (DefaultComboBoxModel) 
        cmbo0.getModel(); 
        model.addElement(a); 

            cmbo0.setSelectedItem(a);
```

Comment: You'll need a permanent datasource that you can write to, i.e. file, database, etc.

Comment: When we go to the property of the GUI component and set the model property for the comboBox, it stays permanent. I was wondering if there's a way where without the use of database, model property can be changed and thus the item remain even after the program is terminated.

Comment: The other way is to write to a file or property object. Adding permanent items at runtime can not be achieved if they are not being stored on a disk somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, your combobox only lives as long as your application.

You'll need a permanent datasource that you can write to, i.e. file, database, etc.

Take a look at these links:

- [Connecting to a database](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html)
- [Reading and Writing from a File](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42)